# Reactjs: create table from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am using React JS and I have this js array:

```
(7) [Array(4), Array(4), Array(4), Array(4), Array(4), Array(4), Array(4)]
0: (4) ["050222222", "field", "field", "field"]
1: (4) ["050222222", "field", "field", "field"]
2: (4) ["050222222", "field", "field", "field"]
3: (4) ["050222222", "field", "field", "field"]
4: (4) ["050222222", "field", "field", "field"]
5: (4) ["050222222", "field", "field", "field"]
6: (4) ["050222222", "field", "field", "field"]
length: 7
```

What I am trying to do is create a table with the content of the array.
Let's say:

```
Phone         |   Full Name    | Custom1  | Custom2 | Custom3 |
0502222222        field           field     field     field
0502222222        field           field     field     field
0502222222        field           field     field     field
0502222222        field           field     field     field
0502222222        field           field     field     field
0502222222        field           field     field     field
```

But I want it to be able to add other fields (for example if I am adding another 'custom', I want it to create another td so it will be equal).

What I've tried (myData is a useState variable that holds the js array above):

```
    const createTable = () => {

    if (myData == undefined) return <div>Nothing</div>;
    const Table = () => (<table><tbody>{myData.map(generateRow)}</tbody></table>);
    const generateRow = rowData => (<tr>{rowData.map(generateCell)}</tr>);
    const generateCell = cellData => (<td>{cellData}</td>);

    return (
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>Phone</th>
                    <th>Full Name</th>
                    <th>Custom1</th>
                    <th>Custom2</th>
                    <th>Custom3</th>
                </tr>
                {Table()}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    )
}
```

The problem is that everything is appearing in the "phone" field.  I also want it to be flexible if I add a new field it will add the field to another "custom".

Comment: What do you mean "everything is concentrated inside the phone field"? Do you mean all the text is appearing in the phone column? If so your data shape probably doesn't match what you expect. Can you post the actual data, not a copy paste from the Chrome inspector output?

Comment: @AndyRay yes, all the text is appearing in the phone column. I am getting the data from handlePaste, I copy Excel data into the textarea and then I console.log it. But if I see it in Chomre inspector output, then it means it is the actual array, or am I wrong?

Comment: I can advise you to use material ui. [data-grid demo](https://material-ui.com/components/data-grid/demo/)

Comment: @Hoxz thank you for the advise, but I am trying to make this work first before styling it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is your `Table()` also have again `table` tag. Just remove the `Table()` and use directly `{myData.map(generateRow)}`.

Also, make sure, data also has 5 columns (similar to count of `th`).

Update: Handle to add the columns dynamically based on data column size.

```js
const CreateTable = (props) => {
   
    if (myData == undefined) return <div>Nothing</div>;
    const generateRow = rowData => (<tr>{rowData.map(generateCell)}</tr>);
    const generateCell = cellData => (<td>{cellData}</td>);
    
    const all_cols = ['Phone', 'Full Name', 'Custom1', 'Custom2', 'Custom3'];
    
    const generateHeader = (count) => (<tr>{all_cols.slice(0, count).map((name) => <th>{name}</th>)}</tr>);

    return (
        <table>
            <tbody>
                {generateHeader(props.myData[0].length)}
                {props.myData.map(generateRow)}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    )
}

   const myData = [["050222222", "field", "field", "field", "field"],
                    ["050222222", "field", "field", "field", "field"]]
                    
     const myData2 = [["050222222", "field"],
                    ["050222222", "field"]]

ReactDOM.render(<CreateTable myData={myData2} />, document.getElementById("app"))
```

```css
th, td {
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Can't believe I didn't notice! that worked perfectly, thank you! Is there a way to create the th fields according to the fields I get? without adding the <th> at all? I only need the "phone" field TH to stay, that's all. thanks again.

Comment: @OrNakash,  Glad to hear that. You can try building the Header dynamically based on the columns of the data you receive. Updated the answer with one way to do it.  (Alternatively, you can pass the columns as prop if need more flexibility).

Comment: is there a way to limit the columns to only 3 columns? I have this code: ```const data = clipText.trim().split(/\r\n|\n|\r/).map(row => row.split('\t'));``` basically it takes data from an excel file (copy paste) and makes an array based on it

Comment: @OrNakash, You can slice the data. I think, `.map(row =>row.split('\t').slice(0, 3)` should work.